# why use Dynamic Page Generation

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

please check the following URL

**https://XXX.com/admin/products/115717172**

when you open it it will show you one product detail. so my question is as a developer if i want my user to show some product the url for that is something like this
**https://XXX.com/viewProducst.jsp?productId=xxx**

i have seen in every major sites that they all are using either above Url or use only html page with name of specific products for that URL.

is this any load balancing technique ? 
why they are using this technique instead of passing just one specific code ?

if you have confusion what i am asking don't close this question.my question is very logical just i could not explain here correctly.even when i save question here so will so it with specific URL which contains my question title.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: The first URL is usually handled by a rewrite rule in the server, which translates it to a URL like the second one.

Comment: @Barmar Usually yes. But I've also seen some content management system that writes static pages to disk for content that is more or less static (no need to dynamically generate it every time). Just to speed up access and lessen the burden on the server. Anyway, what you are saying is most likely the most common method.

Comment: Also some prefer the rewrite version because it look better and is usually considered to be more SEO friendly than the other version. See http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ and http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is most likely done by a URL rewrite. URL rewriting is done because it is friendlier to read (cleaner and more describing) for both the user and search engine robots (SEO optimization). Here are two good links that I think cover the basics about the subject:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

I've also seen cases where content is more or less static, there are cases like this where it is unnecessary to dynamically generate the content. In this case the final page is either cached in memory, database or on disk to lessen the burden on the server(s).

Comment: i got the URL rewriting  point.whenever i open my bank website i noticed that all the pages i surf are only html pages. how can it be possible to present html pages to user while data is constantly changes and what techniques people use to do so ?

Comment: How do you know that they are not dynamic? It will look like regular HTML to the client. The file ending have nothing to do with it something the website serves as .html can have been dynamically generated. Even something ending with .php can be any other language (such as ASP, static HTML or anything else), so the file extension should not be solely used as a measurement of what the file contain or how it is built. Also it is not always necessary to send variables as GET as you suggest, you could use POST, cookies or session variables to keep track of what the user is asking for.

Comment: N I think they use some technique to generate the HTMl file on the fly suppose use XSLT etc. but why they do this instead of providing just response ? any clear advantage of it ?

Comment: @Mihir I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. There are multiple techniques to make dynamic pages, everything is likely not generated dynamically but the system will use static pages (e.g. templates) for what is static and then fill in the dynamic parts where needed.

Comment: Ok.i will research on it and let you know.